# After rebooting all of my existing usb devices stopped working

Tags: usb

I rebooted my system today and discovered that my existing usb keyboard, mouse, and webcam stopped working.  Oddly plugging a spare keyboard and mouse I had lying around works fine!!!

Failing devices

```
Aug 25 19:04:25 tower kernel: [  460.225605] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 11
Aug 25 19:04:27 tower kernel: [  461.975324] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
Aug 25 19:04:27 tower kernel: [  462.141834] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=3070, bcdDevice= 1.01
Aug 25 19:04:27 tower kernel: [  462.141840] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Aug 25 19:04:27 tower kernel: [  462.141843] usb 1-3: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
Aug 25 19:04:27 tower kernel: [  462.141846] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Ralink
Aug 25 19:04:27 tower kernel: [  462.141849] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 1.0
Aug 25 19:04:27 tower mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 12: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3"
Aug 25 19:04:27 tower mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 12 was not an MTP device
Aug 25 19:04:27 tower mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 12: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3"
Aug 25 19:04:27 tower mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 12 was not an MTP device
Aug 25 19:04:32 tower kernel: [  467.175835] usb 1-5.3: USB disconnect, device number 7
Aug 25 19:04:35 tower kernel: [  470.011325] usb 1-5.3: new low-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
Aug 25 19:04:35 tower kernel: [  470.169576] usb 1-5.3: New USB device found, idVendor=056e, idProduct=00fe, bcdDevice= 1.20
Aug 25 19:04:35 tower kernel: [  470.169581] usb 1-5.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Aug 25 19:04:35 tower kernel: [  470.169585] usb 1-5.3: Product: ELECOM TrackBall Mouse
Aug 25 19:04:35 tower kernel: [  470.169587] usb 1-5.3: Manufacturer: ELECOM
Aug 25 19:04:35 tower mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 13: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.3"
Aug 25 19:04:35 tower mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 13 was not an MTP device
Aug 25 19:04:35 tower mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 13: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.3"
Aug 25 19:04:35 tower mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 13 was not an MTP device
Aug 25 19:04:37 tower kernel: [  472.295818] usb 1-5.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
Aug 25 19:04:40 tower kernel: [  474.831304] usb 1-5.1: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
Aug 25 19:04:40 tower kernel: [  474.947631] usb 1-5.1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b, bcdDevice=12.03
Aug 25 19:04:40 tower kernel: [  474.947634] usb 1-5.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Aug 25 19:04:40 tower kernel: [  474.947635] usb 1-5.1: Product: USB Receiver
Aug 25 19:04:40 tower kernel: [  474.947637] usb 1-5.1: Manufacturer: Logitech
Aug 25 19:04:40 tower mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 14: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.1"
Aug 25 19:04:40 tower mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 14 was not an MTP device
Aug 25 19:04:40 tower mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 14: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.1"
Aug 25 19:04:40 tower mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 14 was not an MTP device
```

This works:

```
Aug 25 19:09:26 tower kernel: [  761.299152] usb 1-5.2: new full-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower kernel: [  761.414478] usb 1-5.2: New USB device found, idVendor=062a, idProduct=4102, bcdDevice=81.13
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower kernel: [  761.414483] usb 1-5.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower kernel: [  761.414486] usb 1-5.2: Product: 2.4G Wireless Mouse
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower kernel: [  761.414489] usb 1-5.2: Manufacturer: MOSART Semi.
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower kernel: [  761.420321] input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.2/1-5.2:1.0/0003:062A:4102.0013/input/input20
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower kernel: [  761.479523] input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.2/1-5.2:1.0/0003:062A:4102.0013/input/input21
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower kernel: [  761.481521] hid-generic 0003:062A:4102.0013: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5.2/input0
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 21: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.2"
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 21 was not an MTP device
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2026]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2026]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2026]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse (/dev/input/event4)
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse'
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2026]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse (/dev/input/event4)
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2026]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2026]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2026]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse'
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 47 paused 0
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: always reports core events
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2026]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 25 paused 1
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2026]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:68
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (II) event4  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (II) event4  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: device is a pointer
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (II) event4  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: device removed
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.2/1-5.2:1.0/0003:062A:4102.0013/input/input20/event4"
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (II) event4  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (II) event4  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse: device is a pointer
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse (/dev/input/event5)
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3935]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2026]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse (/dev/input/event5)
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2026]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2026]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 21: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.2"
Aug 25 19:09:27 tower mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 21 was not an MTP device
```

Usb devices:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh=10
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=05.00
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.0.0-25-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#= 15 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bc2 ProdID=2100 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Seagate
S:  Product=FreeAgent
S:  SerialNumber=2GE3CT36
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0d8c ProdID=0014 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=C-Media Electronics Inc.
S:  Product=VTIN VNPA081AB
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
I:  If#=0x2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
I:  If#=0x3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=04 Cnt=03 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2109 ProdID=2813 Rev=90.11
S:  Manufacturer=VIA Labs, Inc.
S:  Product=USB2.0 Hub
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=04 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 14 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=046d ProdID=c52b Rev=12.03
S:  Manufacturer=Logitech
S:  Product=USB Receiver
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=98mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#=0x2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=04 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#= 21 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=062a ProdID=4102 Rev=81.13
S:  Manufacturer=MOSART Semi.
S:  Product=2.4G Wireless Mouse
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=04 Port=02 Cnt=03 Dev#= 13 Spd=1.5 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=056e ProdID=00fe Rev=01.20
S:  Manufacturer=ELECOM
S:  Product=ELECOM TrackBall Mouse
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=04 Port=03 Cnt=04 Dev#= 18 Spd=1.5 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=413c ProdID=2113 Rev=01.08
S:  Product=Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=05.00
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.0.0-25-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out a week or two ago I cleaned out a bunch of orphaned kernel debs for space.  And some how I removed linux-modules-extras....  It was just shear luck that my old devices all had drivers in the base modules deb.